# heatmap using geom_tile in ggplot2() - looking for the equivalent of older code

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I've got a data frame with three variables: location, weather, and wc.

I'd like to make a heatmap using  geom_tile in ggplot2(), so that weather is on the y axis, location on the x axis, and wc being the fill. I found some code on https://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/ggplot2-quick-heatmap-plotting/, producing exactly the kind of plot I'm looking for.

The problem's that while I can make the basic plot (p), I can't get the code for the finishing touches to work (there's a visual of the end product on the webpage). As far as I can tell some of the code is for older versions of ggplot2(), but I can't figure out what the updated equivalent is.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Starting point (df):

```
df1 <- data.frame(location=c("az","az","az","bi","bi","ca","ca","ca"),weather=c(1,2,3,2,3,1,2,3),wc=c(2,1,1,2,1,2,2,1))
```

Current code:

```
p <- ggplot(df1, aes(location,weather)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = wc),colour = "white") +
 scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "steelblue")

p + theme_grey(base_size = base_size) + labs(x = "", y = "") + 
    scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) + scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) + 
    opts(legend.position = "none", axis.ticks = theme_blank(), axis.text.x = theme_text(size = base_size * 0.8, angle = 330, hjust = 0, colour = "grey50"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an updated version:

```
base_size <- 9
ggplot(df1, aes(location,weather)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = wc),colour = "white") +
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "steelblue") +
    theme_grey(base_size = base_size) + labs(x = "", y = "") + 
    scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) + scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) + 
    theme(legend.position = "none",
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          axis.text.x = element_text(size = base_size * 0.8,
                                      angle = 330,
                                      hjust = 0,
                                      colour = "grey50"))
```

all arguments under `opts` should be inside `theme`

`theme_text()` is replaced with `element_text()`
`theme_blank()` is replaced with `element_blank()`

[image]